# ¿Cómo puedo crear una matriz de objetos con numpy en Python?

Tags: python, numpy

Lo que busco es crear una matriz que contenga objetos, ya sean instancias de clases, o algún tipo de diccionario o un vector, pero con numpy no he podido, esto es lo que intenté

```
gameState = np.full((nxC, nyC), fill_value=['A', 'M', '0', '0', '1'])
print(gameState)
```

Pero me da un error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5,) into shape (100,100)
```

Comment: Buen día, ¿Podrías agregar un ejemplo de lo que esperarías obtener? Según lo que entiendo desearías que `['A', 'M', '0', '0', '1']` se repitiera en cada "celda" de la matriz ¿Entendí bien?

Comment: supongo que es por los valores que tiene (nxC,nyC) en donde nyC tiene un valor distinto de 5 que es el vector que le estás pasando